# Does FaceTime support 1-to-many connections (conference call) or only 1:1 video calls?

Tags: facetime

I want to do a video conference call. My understanding is that FaceTime is a 1:1 video chat, but wanted to confirm that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FaceTime is currently a one to one connection on both Mac OS X and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Facetime is only one to one. Try Skype, or even iChat if all clients are using Macs.